# HKHealthStore read permissions

Tags: healthkit

I'm working on an app that has `HealthKit integration`. I would like to know if

`requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(healthKitTypesToWrite, readTypes: healthKitTypesToRead) {}`

gives my app permission to read `HealthKit` data that was sent to `HealthKit` by another app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the user agrees.

Be also aware that the user can choose which source wins, if two apps write at the same time.

Depending how you select, you can also get data from all sources even if they've written at the same time.